# What does FIFA 2011's secret 100 pt. achievement entail? 

Tags: xbox-360, achievements, fifa-11

Anyone know what this achievement entails? I have never seen someone who has it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"FIFA for the life" - Spend 50 hours on the pitch

Comment: Can you provide anymore detail?  Is this real time or game time?  Does it include Arena practicing?  Regardless thanks for insight!

Comment: It's in game time. Don't know about Arena, but i doubt it count.

Comment: It's only game time and while the clock is moving. You're looking at 300 games with 5 minute halves. You can check your progress under My FIFA 11, it will show you how many games you've played in there.